# I'm having trouble integrating Webflow and Grow by TradeDoubler

Tags: backend, webflow

I'm having trouble integrating Webflow and Grow by TradeDoubler.
I have a website, [www.seode.ai](http://www.seode.ai), that I want to integrate with Grow by TradeDoubler, but I can't find where to do it anywhere. Does anyone know how to do this? I've received a code from Grow by TradeDoubler, but it's not working because it doesn't generate a unique ID for each product I sell.
Please help me! :D

I need a solution to be able to integrate the two together. Their support has never worked with Webflow before. ^^